# React Native <Image /> not showing, yet I am doing everything right

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Text style={{ marginTop: 50 }}> HELLOOx</Text>
  <Image
    style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
    source={{
      uri:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg",
    }}
  />
  <Image
    source={{
      uri:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/23/18/05/burger-500054_1280.jpg",
    }}
    style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

The first image does not load, yet the second one does. Any guesses?[image]

Comment: The same code working fine for me.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code above... its totally working fine...

Answer (score 0):

For some odd and weird reason, it started loading images again.I found that these images have content-type: / webp even though they are .jpg.  I added the below 2 lines

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.10.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.10.0'
```

in "*\node_modules\unimodules-app-loader\android*"

Then I restarted the app but it did not work. I kept hitting refresh then on the emulator I pressed CTRL-Z by mistake, the app crashed, then when I restarted it, it started loading them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is right in your code . just change your image URI to something like your posted image in above to see difference . problem is not in your code or RN